# Minima Elementwise in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have two columns of data: A and B.

I need a column C with elementwise minima between A and B data.

For instance:

[image]

If I put in C:

= MIN ($A$1:$A$3; $B$1:$B$3)

Then I get a single number, the minimum of all data (in our case 1).

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question: but why don't you use `=MIN(A1;B1)`in C1 and drill the formula down?

Comment: @Ike In this way I'd need to write such a condizion for each row. My fault, probably I explained my problem worse

Comment: hmmm - did you try to use a table (insert > table)? Tables automatically expand formulas to a new row - no need to write them per row. If you use the formula, that you selected as answer, you have to be aware that you have to adjust the range every time you add new rows. Maybe that is no requirement right now ... but who knows, propably in two months you have more data ...

Comment: @Ike Thanks for your suggestion, that's very helpful. I'll try playing with tables more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use

```
=IF(A1:A3<B1:B3,A1:A3,B1:B3)
```

Or, a little fancier (depending if available to you):

```
=BYROW(A1:B3,LAMBDA(arr,MIN(arr)))
```

This will spill all minima when using Microsoft365.

Comment: Great! That's perfect and allows me to do such an elementwise operation wothout manually writing the formula for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.You just need your formula to be `=MIN(A1:B1)` at row 1 and then drag down.

Notice there are not `$` so we are using relative references. That way you can get minimun value between A and B values at same row, not **all** values.

> [Switch between relative, absolute, and mixed
> references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In cell C1, you put following formula:

```
=MIN(A1;B1)
```

You select cell C1, you put your mouse-cursor in the right-bottom part of cell C1 until the cursor changes in a small cross, you start dragging and you drop once cell C3 is filled.

You will see following formula:

In cell C2:

```
=MIN(A2; B2)
```

In cell C3:

```
=MIN(A3; B3)
```

As you see, there's no need to use absolute references (the ones with the dollarsigns) you're using.